# How to pass environment variable to IntelliJ

Tags: shell, intellij-idea, environment-variables, credentials

I'm running Tomcat through IntelliJ. 
My app property file has properties that are filled up by an ENV variable (such as credentials)

```
DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

I don't store my credentials on git and these credentials are fetch at run time from a vault.
So manually hardcoding these credentials in IntelliJ somewhere is a no go.

Is there a way to pass ENV vars to IntelliJ? 
Or have IntelliJ load a var file prior starting tomcat ?
Or have IntelliJ read the ENV vars of the host (OSX shell in this case)?

Answer (score 2):

Run -> Edit configurations -> Environment variables

[image]

Comment: The Tomcat 'Run' config doesn't have these options?

Comment: I mean it does have a way to pass "Environment variables" but in a static way. I was more interested to an easier setting where IntelliJ reads them from a file (file that could be dynamically generated before hand)

Comment: `The Tomcat 'Run' config doesn't have these options?` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603835/intellij-tomcat-run-configuration-does-not-set-environment-variables

Comment: @Marco That's nowhere to be seen in your original question. Unfortunately I don't know how to pass environment variables from a file to IntelliJ. You can however make as many run configuration with different values as you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Bash, export your environment variables in **~/.bash_profile**:

```
export DB_PASSWORD=*password_here*
```

Intellij by default runs Bash in non-interactive mode, so it doesn't load ~/.bashrc.